# .net core 3.1 odbc driver connection failed in debug mode

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, db2, odbc

I created 2 odbc connection (32 and 64 bit) to connect with iseries access odbc driver (db2 IBM)
it works while publish in IIS , but while debugging raise this error ERROR [42000] [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS],
I tried it with asp .net web forms and it worked in debug mode but the problem is with .net core 3.1 in debug mode

environment
windows server 2019 standard and
visual studio 2019 community

stake trace

```
at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleError(OdbcHandle hrHandle, RetCode retcode)
 at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, Boolean needReader, Object[] methodArguments, SQL_API odbcApiMethod)
 at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, Boolean needReader)
 at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
 at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReader()
 at AKM.Repositories.PartyRepository.GetPersonInfo(String IdNo, Int32 IdType) in C:\mojpros-v2\AKMProsecution\AKM.Repository\PartyRepository.cs:line 90
```

Comment: Behaviour can be specific to versions and applied fixes for the i Access ODBC driver.  Enable tracing (refer to its documentation about cwbtrc) and see what is happening under the covers. Put detailed information into your question , not as comments, otherwise your question may be unanswered.

Comment: Which of the 32-bit and 64-bit you are using has problems? You can read the community discussion, which may help you: https://forums-iis.azureedge.net/t/1197019.aspx

Comment: 64 bit, because .net core use 64 bit @Chaodeng

Comment: @mao added the stake trace of the error